socketio.emit statement not updating browser when called from timer driven function
I'm quite new to Python and Flask and I'm writing a simple program for an online game where people join the game, the host enters a word into their admin area and the players have to guess the word. There is a timer set and once the time is reached, if no one has guessed the word, the leaderboard is shown. If someone does guess the word, the leaderboard is shown before the timer expires.
I can't work out why the leaderboard displays in the browser fine when called from the function which assesses if a players input matches the game word, but doesn't work when the exact same function is called from the timer process.
I've put logging throughout and both paths correctly report their status and have the correct variables in play.
This is the function (update_leaderboard) which works fine when called by the function that determines a players guess matches the game word, but not from the function which is part of the timer path.
def update_leaderboard():
    logging.debug(f"Players before updating leaderboard: {game_state['players']}")
    leaderboard = sorted(
        game_state["players"].values(),
        key=lambda p: p["score"],
        reverse=True
    )
    game_state["leaderboard"] = leaderboard
    if not leaderboard:
        payload = {"leaderboard": [{"name": "No winners this round", "score": 0}]}
    else:
        payload = {"leaderboard": leaderboard}

    logging.info(f"Emitting update_leaderboard with payload: {payload}")
    socketio.emit("update_leaderboard", payload, to=None)

submit_answer function that calls the update_leaderboard function and all works as expected:
@socketio.on("submit_answer")
def handle_answer(data):
    sid = request.sid
    answer = data.get("answer", "").strip()

    logging.debug(f"Player {sid} submitted answer: {answer}")
    logging.debug(f"Current players: {game_state['players']}")

    # Ensure the round_word is set
    if not game_state["round_word"]:
        logging.error("Round word is not set.")
        emit("error", {"message": "Round word is not set."}, to=sid)
        return

    # Ensure the player exists in game_state
    if sid not in game_state["players"]:
        logging.error(f"Player with sid {sid} not found in game_state['players'].")
        emit("error", {"message": "Player not found. Please join the game first."}, to=sid)
        return

    # Ensure the "score" key exists
    game_state["players"][sid].setdefault("score", 0)

    # Validate the player's answer
    correct = answer.lower() == game_state["round_word"].lower()
    if correct:
        submission_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = submission_time - game_state["start_time"]
        points = max(100 - int(elapsed_time * 10), 0)

        if not isinstance(points, (int, float)):
            logging.error(f"Invalid points value: {points}")
            emit("error", {"message": "Invalid points calculation."}, to=sid)
            return

        game_state["players"][sid]["score"] += points
        logging.info(f"Player {sid} scored {points} points.")
        update_leaderboard()  # Update leaderboard after a correct answer
    else:
        logging.info(f"Player {sid} gave an incorrect answer.")

end-round function driven by ent_round_timer function that also calls update_leaderboard and no display update takes place:
def end_round_timer(duration):
    logging.info(f"Starting end_round_timer with duration: {duration} seconds.")
    threading.Timer(duration, end_round).start()

def end_round():
    logging.info("Ending round and updating leaderboard.")
    update_leaderboard()
    logging.info("Called update_leaderboard.")
    socketio.emit("round_ended", {"leaderboard": game_state["leaderboard"]}, to=None)

This is the JS the is executed by update_leaderboard:
socket.on("update_leaderboard", (data) => {
    console.log("Received update_leaderboard event:", data);

    const leaderboardElement = document.getElementById("leaderboard-screen");
    if (leaderboardElement) {
        leaderboardElement.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing leaderboard
        if (data.leaderboard.length === 0) {
            const li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = "No winners this round.";
            leaderboardElement.appendChild(li);
        } else {
            data.leaderboard.forEach((player, index) => {
                const li = document.createElement("li");
                li.textContent = `${index + 1}. ${player.name} - ${player.score} points`;
                leaderboardElement.appendChild(li);
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.warn("Leaderboard element not found.");
    }
});

and finally, the HTML code to display the data:
  <div id="leaderboard-screen">
      <h3>Leaderboard</h3>
      <ul id="leaderboard"></ul>
  </div>

So far, I've added logging, moved various statements about, included another call to update_leaderboard() from an unrelated part of the code-base (which also works!). I've put print() statements throughout to track that variables are initialising and have a value, and show as expected when displayed.
I could understand it if calling update_leaderboard() didn't work at all, but I'm at a loss as to why it works only when called from some locations in the code.
